# How to get text on PDF file in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf, vuejs2

I want to get the text by page number from PDF file in client side from VueJS.
Is there any library to get it?

Comment: probably - have you searched for such library since library requests are off topic here?

Comment: yes, i've tried to use pdf-to-text but nothing works

Comment: you've tried one library and nothing works - try more libraries until you find the one that does what you want